# Does anyone know of any clinical psychology journals that use a double-blind review process?

Tags: clinical-psychology

Through this question:

[What kind of cognitive psych journals are receptive to clinicians without any publications?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9672/what-kind-of-cognitive-psych-journals-are-receptive-to-clinicians-without-any-pu)

I found out that a colleague of mine should submit a paper she is writing to a clinical psychology journal that uses a double-blind review process. For those who don't know, that means the reviewers don't know who wrote the article and vice versa.

However, I failed to find any such journal through googling.

**My Question:**

Does anyone happen to know of such a journal? I am looking for one that might accept an article (of a colleague of mine) written on ADHD, a learning disability.

If no such journal exists, what is the closest substitute that still uses a double-blind review process?

**Note:**

As I mentioned in the previous question, my colleague has developed a process model of the disorder based on 25+ years of clinical practice. She has used her model for several years now and is looking to publish her it to help others better understand the disease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My impression is that many (perhaps most) psychology journals do double-blind review (or at least give you the option).

Journal of Consulting and Clinical Psychology is one example.
http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/ccp/?tab=4

> This journal uses a masked reviewing system for all submissions.

It sounds like that (a) you are not aware of what clinical psychology journals exist in your area; and (b) how to determine whether they require or allow for masked review. I'll discuss each of these points.

**Finding a relevant clinical psychology journal:** If you are writing a journal article, you will need to perform a review of the literature. Identify journals from those that you cite in your references. There are also various lists of journals organised by topic (e.g., Science Citation Index) that often give an indication of journal prestige. If you are interested in clinical psychology, then you may also want to check out "psychiatry" journals as well.

**Determining review policy.** Every journal has a website, and a section of the website will include instructions to authors. Here you will typically find information about the reviewing process.

Comment: How do I determine whether they do or don't? Like how did you find this one? I really did google a bit but simple searching "double-blind review" and "clinical" and "psychology" didn't turn up results. I thought it surely would but I failed and obviously you were more successful.

Comment: Ah, they use a different name "masked review". I wonder if that is why I didn't find this.