# What are the highest ranked neuroscience journals that use double-blind review process?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, publication-process, publication

In terms of impact factor (for a lack of a better proxy), what are the highest ranked neuroscience journals that use double-blind review process?

I would be submitting a paper that combines neuroscience, psychology and machine learning.

Comment: Why the fixation on double-blind review?

Comment: I don't know the particulars of your case, but it is usually a big red flag when someone thinks that their work deserves a top journal but do not know the top journals of the field in which the work is in. That usually signals a certain amount of disengagement with the literature, my personal advice on how to proceed [would be here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/104/66). However, I think your question is a fine fit for this site and I hope you get some useful answers.

Answer (score 5):

**Nature Neuroscience** offers such a possibility.

http://www.nature.com/news/nature-journals-offer-double-blind-review-1.16931

See also

[Does anyone know of any clinical psychology journals that use a double-blind review process?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9689/does-anyone-know-of-any-clinical-psychology-journals-that-use-a-double-blind-rev)